# Why is OpenEars giving over 50 errors within my app in XCode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, openears

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I implement voice recognition into my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014965/how-can-i-implement-voice-recognition-into-my-ios-app)

I am trying to implement [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears) and I have completed all the steps exactly as they state on the [website](http://www.politepix.com/openears/configuring).

Why am I getting the following errors?:

[image]

You can see the errors in text only form [here](http://pastie.org/2831947).

I am using XCode 4.2 with my iPhone having iOS 5 installed.

I would really appreciate some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Can you copy and paste the text, it's too hard to read in that image.

Comment: righclick -> view image enlarges it.

Comment: hence the reason I put "You can see the errors in text only form here." - click on "here"

Comment: or see it directly at: http://pastie.org/2831947

Comment: Please update your original question with this new information, don't ask what is effectively a duplicate.

Comment: it is nothing like my other question. You closed it for absolutely no reason whatsoever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say one of the following things are wrong:

1. One of the libraries is not or not properly added to the project.
2. The 'valid architectures' is not set properly (click on the project file (with the blue thing in front) -> select the correct project -> click on build settings). It should probably say `armv6 armv7`.

These are the only 2 things i can think of.

Comment: how can I add the library to the project? :S

Comment: If you have the framework file on your machine just drag and drop it inside the Frameworks folder.

Comment: libOpenEarsLibrary.a seems to be the one missing.

Comment: it's not missing, it is there. See: http://f.cl.ly/items/2D3s1W2h1l1J0Z0B0924/frameworks.tiff

Comment: Have you checked the second thing? does it say both armv6 and armv7?

Comment: Hmmm perculiar.. Can't think of anything that could be wrong apart from these things, Sorry.